# TypeError: init() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
def main():
    sc = scraper.Scraper()
    sc.load_url()
    for _ in range(SCROLL_RANGE):
        time.sleep(1)
        sc.scroll_down()
    time.sleep(5)
    sc.read_data()
    print(sc.get_hrefs())
    sc.get_info('https://www.carwale.com' + '/used/cars-in-delhi/renault-kwid-2019-d2328551/?slot=4&rk=4&isP=true')
    time.sleep(3000)
    sc.load_url()
    print("Hello Script")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/webscraper/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()


  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/webscraper/main.py", line 15, in main
    sc.get_info('https://www.carwale.com' + '/used/cars-in-delhi/renault-kwid-2019-d2328551/?slot=4&rk=4&isP=true')


  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\webscraper\scraper.py", line 29, in get_info
    cf = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#overview > div > ul'))


TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

```
class Scraper:
def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\gkhat\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
    self.url = "http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-for-sale/#sc=-1&so=-1&pn=1"
    self.hrefs = []
def get_hrefs(self):
    return self.hrefs
def load_url(self):
    self.driver.get(self.url)
def scroll_down(self):
    self.driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)')
def read_data(self):
    main = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[12]/form/section[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]')
    soup = bs(main.get_attribute("innerHTML"), "html.parser")
    for elem in soup.findAll('h2', {'class': 'card-detail-block__title'}):
        print(elem.a['href'])
        self.hrefs.append(str(elem.a['href']))
def get_info(self, url):
    self.driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)
    cf = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#overview > div > ul'))
    soup = bs(cf.get_attribute("innerHTML"), "html.parser")
    for li in soup.find_all('li'):
        print(li.text)
```

Comment: Please show us your import of `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cf = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#overview > div > ul')))
```

you have to pass a tuple to the EC.presence of element